# Android: Opening Video via MediaExtractor contains no tracks

Tags: android, video, mediaextractor

I'm having problems to open a video file with the MediaExtractor.
The Video: http://video.blendertestbuilds.de/download.blender.org/ED/ED_HD.avi
The Code:

```
extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(mUrl);
Log.d("DecodeActivity", String.format("TRACKS #: %d", extractor.getTrackCount()));
```

The Log:

```
06-10 02:08:13.901: I/MediaExtractor(3771):  Using ExtendedExtractor mime = video/avi 
06-10 02:08:13.901: I/MediaExtractor(3771): mime = video/avi
06-10 02:08:13.951: I/AviExtractor(3771): addTracks in
06-10 02:09:24.281: D/DecodeActivity(3771): TRACKS #: 0
```

So you can see that my main problem ist, that there are no tracks in this movie file.
I played the same movie with the built in MoviePlayer App and it is playing fine.
I also played other videos with the above code (h.264), without any problems.
Can you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong?
I don't see any error message in Logcat.
This all runs under Android 4.4

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This video file has MPEG-4 video track and AC3 audio track. Morelikely MediaExtractor does not support these codecs